# Gradle Build Failed - Gradle version 1.10 is required. Current version is 2.8

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-2.0

[![enter image description here][1]][1][image]

I have modified the file .but still not working. Can you please tell exactly where I am going wrong.  previously,It was showing error-
Required gradle 1.10 , but currently using 2.8

Comment: Quick fix is getting failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to Settings > Builds ,Execution , Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle and set  **Use default gradle wrapper**

[image]

2. Edit the `Project\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties` file and set the field `distributionUrl`  with:

   `distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip`
3. Move the gradle plugin outside the `dependecies` block and inside the `buildscript` block:

Somenthing like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks .. I am trying it.. In distributionUrl it should be 2.10 or 1.10?

Comment: Sir, It may be a silly question.  Can you tell where to find the buildscript? or I need to write these lines by myself?  I am not finding buildscript code inside build.gradle

Comment: @Sourav usually the buildscript block is inside the top level file (the build.gradle file in the root of the project). About the gradle version you can use 2.10.

Comment: Sir, Sorry for disturbing you again and again. Actually, i have imported this project from Eclipse Juno. I have updated my post with top level build.gradle file Image. There is no buildscript as you can see.

Comment: @Sourav You can copy the part. In any case you can try to create a blank project to undestand better what I am writing.

Comment: ok!!! Thank you so much for Your response. I will update you about it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Sir,  I did everything you said. Now the error coming is written below--- Error:The project is using an unsupported version of the Android Gradle plug-in (0.12.2). The recommended version is 1.5.0.
Fix plugin version and sync project

Comment: the version of the gradle plugin is exactly the number used in the buildscript block

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, My app had other issues as well. Finally, It got solved. It took almost 8 hrs.. OMG!!! btw, /thanks for your help. SIr.

Answer (score 0):

It might help people like me-

1. I was adding dependencies in the wrong gradle.build file.
2. Later I placed .jar files in /lib folder and connected that to gradle.build
3. I updated my Sdk as well.

Comment: I followed above instructions given by- @Gabriele Mariotti Sir. That help me to actually find and solve the issue.